# Where do I confirm my kernel version is safe against intel meltdown

Tags: kernel, security

I'm worried about the intel hardware level meltdown hacking. Several days ago, I experienced my Ubuntu system malfunctioning from booting. It went to something like initramfs. I couldn't fix the issue so I changed the kernel to previous version, 4.10. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.) Then it succeeded to boot normally. However I'm now worried since I feel like I should use the newer version that had issue booting. What should I do? Where do I confirm which version kernel is safe?

Comment: I followed the link and went to the page where new kernel exists. Then why are there the lower versions like 4.4??

Comment: Because of [backporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting).

Comment: how do I download it and install it?? It is too much work. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source bash script which checks vulnerabilities of your kernel and tells if it is patched.

```
 wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/master/spectre-meltdown-checker.sh

 sudo chmod +x spectre-meltdown-checker.sh
```

and run it with root privileges

```
 sudo sh spectre-meltdown-checker.sh
```

For more info : https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker